# How to do the following Query in Doctrine with multiple entities?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine

I have 2 tables: `comment` and `user`

on `comment` I have the following columns: `id`, `user_id`, `conversation_id`, `body` ...

and on `user` I have the following columns: `id`, `username` ...

I would like to perform the following query with doctrine:

```
"SELECT c.*, u.username FROM comment c LEFT JOIN user u on c.user_id = u.id WHERE c.conversation_id = '5'"
```

In other words when I get the list of comments I would like to display the `name` which is in the `user` table.

I know how to do it in SQL but I can't manage to do it in doctrine.

It should look something like this:

```
$q = $this
    ->createQueryBuilder('u')
    ->where('u.conversationId = :conversationId')
    ->setParameter('conversationId', $conversationId)
    ->getQuery();
```

Doctrine Comment Entity:

```
Test\SocialBundle\Entity\Comment:
type: entity
table: comment
repositoryClass: Test\SocialBundle\Entity\CommentRepository
fields:
    id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
    conversationId:
        type: integer
        nullable: false
        column: conversation_id
    userId:
        type: integer
        nullable: false
        column: user_id
    body:
        type: string
        nullable: false
        length: '300'
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Doctrine User Entity:

```
Test\UserBundle\Entity\User:
type: entity
table: user
repositoryClass: Test\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository
fields:
    id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
    username:
        type: string
        length: '100'
        nullable: true
        column: username
    name:
        type: string
        length: '100'
        nullable: true
        column: name
manyToMany:
    roles:
        targetEntity: Role
        joinTable:
            name: user_role
            joinColumns:
                user_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            inverseJoinColumns:
                role_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the Doctrine entities' structure. As you may know using `ORM` shift logic towards the object instead of to foreign keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must call request from CommentRepository, and it must looks like

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');
$qb->select('c, u.username')
   ->leftJoin('c.userId', 'u')
   ->where($qb->expr()->eq('c.conversationId', $conversationId));
$qb->getQuery();
```